# Calculating probability of addition of two binary sequences to be binary

Tags: probability

I have two binary vectors of length 66, $x=(x_1,x_2,..,x_{66})$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,.., y_{66})$ with $x_1+x_2+..+x_{66}=y_1+y_2+..+y_{66}=22$. Thus $x_i,y_i \in \{0,1\}$ with Hamming weight of $x$ and $y$ are 22. Now define $x+y$ componentwise. Thus $x+y=(x_1+y_1, ..., x_{66}+y_{66})$. What is the probability all $x_i+y_i \in \{0,1\}$? Since we need $x_j+y_j \neq 2$, probability should be $\frac{\binom{66-22}{22}}{\binom{66}{22}} =2^{-16.40}$.

Now I want to calculate this probability using different idea. Probability $x_{66}+y_{66} \neq 2$ is $\frac{8}{9}$ since both $x_{66}=y_{66}=1$ hold with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. Thus we have 3 possible pairs $(x_{66},y_{66})=(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$. Among these 3 pairs, I take one pair randomly and accordingly calculate the probability $x_{65}$ and $y_{65}$ to be 1 and go like this way. Of course, I know this idea can not give an exact probability, I expect approximation. But I am not getting like this way.
This is my Sage Code. Any idea?

```
n=66
P1=[2*n/3,  n/3 ]
P2=[2*n/3,  n/3]

A=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0]]
aa=0

for i in range(n):
  f=0
  for j in range(len(A)):  
    
    if(A[j][0]==0):
       p=(P1[0])/(P1[0]+P1[1])
    else:
       p=P1[1]/(P1[0]+P1[1])

    if(A[j][1]==0):
       q=P2[0]/(P2[0]+P2[1])
    else:
       q=P2[1]/(P2[0]+P2[1])

    
    if(p<=0 or q<=0 ):
       continue
    f=f+p*q





  aa=aa+ round(log(f)/log(2) ,10)
  print(aa,i,f)


  while(1):
    j=ZZ.random_element(len(A))
    
    if((A[j][0]==0 and P1[0]<=0)    or  (A[j][0]==1 and P1[1]<=0)   or  (A[j][1]==0 and P2[0]<=0)  or  (A[j][1]==1 and P2[1]<=0) ):
       continue
    break 

  
  if(A[j][0]==0):
   
    P1[0]=P1[0]-1  
  else:
    
    P1[1]=P1[1]-1 


  if(A[j][1]==0):
    
    P2[0]=P2[0]-1

  else:
    
    P2[1]=P2[1]-1  

  print(P1,P2)
```

Comment: The difference arises because the component-wise sums aren't independent.  If the Hamming weights of $x$ and $y$ were (say) $34$, then the assumption of independence would lead to a value of about $1$ in $730$ million, but in fact the probability is $0$ by application of the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can we use this idea to the approximation? 1/730 million is also close to zero.

Comment: I would not say that is necessarily generalizable.  Take the smaller case where $x$ and $y$ are both vectors of length $3$ and weight $2$.  Then the independence assumption leads to a probability of $(5/9)^3 = 125/729 \approx 0.171$, but again the actual answer is $0$.

Comment: Ok, true. But for large n & where probability is positive, can we say something using simulation?